# Whats is Linq equivalent for SQL query with OR-joins?

Tags: c#, linq

I need multiple condition in Linq Join.

What could be the equivalent of

```
select * 
from tblOfferingBillingBehaviorMapping billMap
inner join tblLookUpBillingBehavior lkpBill 
    on (billMap.LkpBillingBehaviorId =lkpBill.LkpBillingBehaviorId 
        or billMap.LkpBillingBehaviorId =lkpBill.ParentRootId)
```

Comment: No quick answer: LINQ only supports equality for the `join` clause. You could use multiple `from` clauses with a `where`.

Comment: use `functional syntax` for understanding how it works and all be just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do a cross join with a where condition similar to your inner join condition

```
var q1 = from billMap in tblOfferingBillingBehaviorMapping 
         from lkpBill in tblLookUpBillingBehavior 
         where billMap.LkpBillingBehaviorId == lkpBill.LkpBillingBehaviorId || billMap.LkpBillingBehaviorId =lkpBill.ParentRootId
         select new { billMap, lkpBill };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = from [record] in [table]
                        join [table that you join] 
                        in [name of the table] 
                        on [record] equals [record in the other table]
                        select new { [Column Name] = [Table].[Record] };
```

You can do it this way if you use a query.
I don't know how to perform that in linq p => p. style.
Hope this is helpful.
And here is an example:

```
var query = from person in people
                        join pet in pets on person equals pet.Owner
                        select new { OwnerName = person.FirstName, PetName = pet.Name };
```